# Is there a closed form solution to $e^{-x/b}(a+x) = e^{x/b}(a-x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form

I have the following equation
$$e^{-x/b}(a+x) = e^{x/b}(a-x)$$
where $b > 0$, and $a > 0$

I need to solve for $x$. I can do it numerically, but would prefer if there was a closed form solution.

It seems to me that there likely is no closed form solution, but thought I'd ask the experts here, just in case.

Comment: Notice that $e^{-x/b}(a+x)=e^{x/b}(a-x)\iff e^{2x/b}=(a+x)/(a-x)$. Subsitute $y=2x/b$, and obtain $e^y=(2a/b+y)/(2a/b-y)$, so you only have to solve $e^y=(c+y)/(c-y)$, $c>0$.

Comment: Letting $u = \frac{2x}{b}$ in the equation $\exp\left(\frac{2x}{b}\right) = \frac{a+x}{a-x}$ gives $e^u = \frac{2a+bu}{2a-bu},$ and I am nearly certain that this can't be solved explicitly (at least without using something like the Lambert function) even when $a=b=1.$

Comment: Mathematica can't solve the original equation or the one supplied by @DaveL.Renfro not very surprising though. I highly doubt that this can be solved in closed form.

Comment: Another tidy presentation of the equation is $\frac xa = \tanh(\frac xb)$.

Comment: $x=0$ is one solution

Comment: You need the inverse of the [“tanhc” function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TanhcFunction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simple rearranging of the equation shows that the main theorem of [Lin 1983] can be applied that implies that the equation doesn't have solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

Simple rearranging of the equation gives

$$\frac{2a-bz}{2a+bz}e^z=1$$

This shows that the equation is in a form that is not solvable in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). But the equation can be solved by Generalized Lambert W:

$$z=W(^{+\frac{2a}{b}}_{-\frac{2a}{b}};-1)$$

$-$ see the references below.
$\ $

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 1):

Let’s see if the equation can be solved with the [Inverse of the Regularized Gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized/). If I cannot, or others, solve it with the function, then there is probably no closed form. Here is a similar set up with the [Generalized Regularized Gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized3/):

$$Q\left(2,\frac xb,-\frac xb\right)=0\iff e^\frac xb\left(\frac xb-1\right)+e^{-\frac xb}\left(\frac xb+1\right)=0$$

Where the inverse cannot be taken with the Inverse of the Regularized Gamma function proving that one cannot use this function, which is a more general Lambert W function.

*Let me try to find a series reversion of the solution soon*. Alternatively, you will have a closed form with the [Root function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Root/).

Comment: Inverse of $\frac{\tan(x)}x$ may work or [Mellin inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) may on the inverse of $\frac{e^\frac{2x}b(a-x)}{a+x}$ at $x=1$

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a closed form solution to this equation ?*

No. Not even one in terms of [Lambert's *W* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 0):

As Steven Taschuk  commented, the equation can write $$\frac xa = \tanh(\frac xb)$$ Changing variable $x=by$, this write $$\frac {b}{a} y = \tanh(y)$$ Taking into account the shape of $\tanh(y)$ and essentially the fact that, at $y=0$, $\Big(tanh(y)\Big)'=1$, there is a solution only if $a\gt b$. Otherwise, the only possible solution is $y=0$ which is valid for any non zero values of $a$ and $b$. If $y_*$ is a solution, $-y_*$ is the other one. So, we have a maximum of three solutions.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no closed form for the solution and that numerical methods should be required.

Using Taylor expansion to the third order, a first approximation is given by $$y_*= \sqrt{3\frac{a-b}{a}}$$